# Audio Streaming Using J2ME

Tags: java-me

I've got audio online in the form of MP3 files, how do I stream the audio from my J2ME app? A website give the app a list of audio to play, select the audio and it must then stream from the website.

Sample code would be nice. thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no reliable way to ensure that a MIDlet will stream audio data because you don't control how the phone manufacturer implemented [JSR-135](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=135) (the specification that gives you the API to play audio in a MIDlet).

Technically, creating a Java media player using `javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(String aUrl)` should make the JSR-135 implementation stream the audio data located at the url.

Unfortunately, only streaming of very simple audio content (wav more often than mp3), if any, is usually supported over a network connection and, more often than not, a call to `createPlayer(String aUrl)` will throw an exception if the url doesn't begin with "file://"

There are probably devices where the manufacturer managed to plug a more complete audio/networking module into the JSR-135 implementation but finding them will require a lot of testing for you.

Answer (score 2):

J2ME won't let you do this over HTTP. It will download the entire audio before it starts playback. What you need is to host it on an RTP server instead; only then will J2ME stream the audio.

If that's no good, then you might be stuck looking for devices that have their own proprietary libraries for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

There's a better way to do this.
Create your own `InputStream` extended class. *say* `MyHTTPInputStream`, implement all the methods. Run a thread to retrieve the data from HTTP and store it in buffer, when the `Player` class calls `InputStream.read()` method, provide the data from the buffer.

Before implementing this class for `Player`, test the `MyHTTPInputStream` using a dummy WAV file stored in phone memory or add-on card. So, you can know which methods are called from `InputStream` and also you can know the sequence of method calls made by the class `Player`.